# What is the best way to plot an algebraically generated 2d grid in Gnuplot?

Tags: fortran, grid, gnuplot

I have generated a 2d array of x values and an array of y values. Each i,j index corresponds to an x,y point. I want to create a grid from these points, but I am not sure how to go about it. I want to use fortran/GNUPLOT to create this figure. The output should look something like this:

[image]

This was created in matlab where I individually plotted each vertical and horizontal line.

Comment: Write the data to a file where you place a blank line between individual horizontal and vertical lines.  Then read the file with gnuplot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this subroutine should get you what you want:

```
    subroutine gnuplot_output(filename,ni,nj,x,y)
        character(len=*), intent(in) :: filename
        integer, intent(in) :: ni, nj
        real(wp), intent(in) :: x(ni,nj), y(ni,nj)
        
        integer :: unit, i, j

        open(newunit=unit,file=filename)

        do i = 1, ni-1
            do j = 1, nj-1
                write(unit,*) x(i,j), y(i,j)
                write(unit,*) x(i+1,j), y(i+1,j)
                write(unit,*) x(i+1,j+1), y(i+1,j+1)
                write(unit,*) x(i,j+1), y(i,j+1)
                write(unit,*) x(i,j), y(i,j)
                write(unit,*)
            end do
        end do

        close(unit)
    end subroutine
```

Feel free to use the code as desired (any license).

In order, to produce a closed cell you need to output the 4 cell corner coordinates and repeat the first corner coordinate to make gnuplot draw a closed line. A call to the subroutine might look like:

```
real(wp), allocatable :: x(:,:), y(:,:)
integer :: ni, nj

! ... allocate x and y and generate grids ...
! ... the shape(x) == [ni,nj], and shape(y) == [ni,nj]

call gnuplot_output("grid_cells.txt",ni,nj,x,y)
```

In gnuplot all you need to do then is

```
plot "grid_cells.txt" w l
```

The picture below was created in gnuplot using the function:

[image: Quarter grid of a square plate with a circular hole]

Comment: what is the (wp) doing here?

Comment: `wp` is the kind parameter (short for "working precision"). You can replace `wp` with `kind(1.0d0)` for double precision. Generally, it is a good idea to put your subroutines in a module, which would contain  the declaration of `wp`, and can be reused by different procedures.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a gnuplot only version. Do you have your data already in a datafile? Then please show some example data lines. The code would need some changes.

**Code:**

```
### draw grid
reset session

# create some test data
set print $Data
    N=50.       # decimal point! otherwise gnuplot would do integer division
    base(x) = x<1 || x>2 ? 0 : -0.8*(x-1.5)**2+0.2
    do for [y=0:N] {
        y0=y/N
        do for [x=0:N] {
            x0=x/N*3
            y1=(1-base(x0))*y0+base(x0)
            print sprintf("%g %g",x0,y1)
        }
        print "\n"    # add empty line
    }
set print

set view map

splot $Data u 1:2:0 w l notitle
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]